# Select when one of filter-column may not exists

Tags: kdb, k

Suppose a situation when it is not known if a filter column exists.

```
t:([]a:`s1`s2`s3; c:1 2 3);
select c from t where null t[`a]
select c from t where null t[`b]
'length
(where null t[`a])~where null t[`b]
1b
```

It column `a` exists, then the `select` is ok.

But when I use a filter with column `b` (not exists) then I get an error.

1. Why is it happening? - I've checked both of `where` results - they are the same
2. How to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QSQL 'where' needs to act on a list of booleans the same length of the table or of count 1. The count of your example is zero

```
q)t[`b]
`symbol$()
q)count t`b
0
```

Some examples:

```
q)select from t where 0b
a c
---
q)select from t where 00b
'length
  [0]  select from t where 00b
       ^
q)select from t where 000b
a c
---
q)select from t where 0000b
'length
  [0]  select from t where 0000b
       ^
q)select from t where 0#0b
'length
  [0]  select from t where 0#0b
```

Update:
Because you mention the results of 'where', where is wrapped in the QSQL format as opposed to acting independently then the result being applied, so you see the below difference

```
q)where 00b
`long$()
q)select from t where 00b
'length
  [0]  select from t where 00b
       ^
q)select from t `long$()
a c
---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `@` operator to trap the error, so for example

```
q)@[{select c from t where null t[x]};`b;{x}]
"length"
q)@[{select c from t where null t[x]};`a;{x}]
c
-
```

although you don't ned to reference columns like this, if you want to dynamically select columns you can use a functional select, so the equivalent query in functional form would be

```
q)?[`t;enlist(null;`a);0b;(enlist `c)!(enlist `c)]
c
-
```

the syntax here is quite tricky but the `parse` keyword is very useful to figure out the argument you should be using so for example

```
q)parse"select c from t where null a"
?
`t
,,(^:;`a)
0b
(,`c)!,`c
```

shows you the arguments you need. A combination of error trapping and functional queries should help you out with what you're trying to achieve here.